# How do I resize a WebDriverJS browser window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using [WebDriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs), the JavaScript bindings for WebDriver, to do some simple frontend testing (driven by nodejs).  However, I'm running into difficulties resizing the window, and [the documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver_Window.html) is just a bit unclear to me.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-wedriver');

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
           .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
           .build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
.then(function() {
    driver.Window.setSize(400, 400);  // <-- should resize, does nothing
})
// more thenables...
```

Everything works normally and it gives no error, but the browser window does not resize.  Am I referencing this setSize method incorrectly?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After *more than a week* of confused searching through the api docs and google, the answer was actually lying inside  of the tests folder of the [selenium-webdriver tests](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/test/window_test.js) node module!!

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(x, y);
```

Comment: as of May 2018 it's now `driver.manage().window().setRect({width: 640, height: 480, x, y});`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how [selenium-webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) works so I can't help you there but just in case you are interested, here is how it works with [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io):

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

webdriverjs
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .windowHandleSize({width:1024,height:768})
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .title(function(err, res) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
    })
    .end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though it's not really what I need since it would require a fair amount of refactoring. I did find this comment on the differences b/w the two packages, in case anyone wants to know: https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs/issues/138#issuecomment-32051980